# JUnit/Mockito verifying `any(HttpPut.class)` however passes when other instances used too

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a service class that calls a REST API to get, create, update and delete subscribers. The Uri remains the same, but the HTTP method changes as you'd expect. I want to test the correct method is given. Below is an example of the updateSubscriber and its test.

```
public class MyService {

    HttpClient httpClient;

    public MyService(HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    //...

    public int updateSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) throws ... {

        // PUT is the correct method for this request 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute( new HttpPut( "https://example.org/api/subscribers" ) );

        //...
    }

    //...
```

Here is my test with JUnit and Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest 
{

    @Mock
    private HttpClient mockHttpClient;

    @Mock 
    private HttpResponse mockResponse;

    @Mock 
    private StatusLine mockStatusline;

    @Mock 
    private HttpEntity mockEntity;

    // test subject
    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // // this will just ensure http* objects are returning our mocked instances so we can manipulate them..
        // when(mockHttpClient.execute(any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        // when(mockHttpClient.execute(any(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        // when(mockHttpClient.execute(any(HttpPut.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        // when(mockHttpClient.execute(any(HttpDelete.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);

        // when(mockResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusline);
        // when(mockStatusline.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        myService = new MyService(mockHttpClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateSubscriber() throws ...
    {   

        when(mockHttpClient.execute(any(HttpPut.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);

        when(mockResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusline);
        when(mockStatusline.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        String responseString = "...";

        // this is consumed by a static method which we cannot mock, so we must deal with an actual entity instance 
        BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
        entity.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.getBytes()));
        when(mockResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(entity);  

        // create a test case Subscriber instance 
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();

        int statusCode = myService.updateSubscriber(subscriber);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK, statusCode);

        // just confirm that an HTTP request was made 
        // TODO this isn't working, still passes when wrong Http* method used 
        verify(mockHttpClient, times(1)).execute(any(HttpPut.class));
    }

    //...
```

However, when I (wrongfully) have the another Http* method instance, it still passes:

```
// this is wrong, and should fail, but passed :(
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute( new HttpGet( "https://example.org/api/subscribers" ) );
```

I'd really like to be able to test this as the action performed could be wrong if the method is mistaken. This test is to ensure that the PUT method was correctly used with the HTTP request for updateSubscriber. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your version of mockito ? The behaviour of any(class) is different in 1.x

Comment: are you calling this `httpClient.execute( new HttpGet( "https://example.org/api/subscribers" ) );` directly on `httpClient` or `mockHttpClient`? The code above shows you are not making `GET` call on mock

Comment: and also add one more statement to verify `GET` call `verify(mockHttpClient, times(1)).execute(any(HttpGet.class));`

Comment: In the test, you'll see that I'm passing in mockHttpClient as a dependency so it's this instance that receives HttpGet (or Http* whetever method in other cases). I'm using Mockito version 1.9.5.

Answer (score 2):

Test passes because `HtppPut` and `HttpGet` both are implementation classes of `HttpRequestBase`, Change the mocking from `HttpRequestBase` class to `HttpPut` class

```
 when(mockHttpClient.execute(any(HttpPut.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

So now if you try with `GET` call Test will fail with `NullPointerException` since `GET` call has no stub

Comment: I thought that would be the case if I passed `HttpRequestBase.class` in with the `verify`, no? I'm just telling `when` to return the same mocked instance when any implementation of HttpRequestBase is used. Anyway I've changed it as you suggest, and updated my code above, but just passes the same even though I'm verifying that another class instance was passed to `execute` method.

Comment: I have no idea why you are adding stubs in `setup` method and also why do you need all type of stubs @Martyn please take a look at some spring junit examples

Comment: Doesn't setup run prior to each test? I put them here as I didn't want to have to repeat the same code within each test method.

Comment: I don't think so in every method you will call the same `PUT` request @Martyn

Comment: OK, I've moved those lines into the test method from setup for the sake of ruling that out. I have the same issue when I run my tests. I've updated my original post.

Comment: Are you making GET call in the same method? Where is that code? I don't see that code in testUpdateSunscriber @Martyn

Comment: updateSubscriber is called within testUpdateSunscriber. This method calls the execute method of HttpClient - you can see in the first code example. In the last code example, I'm changing this code to pass an instance of HttpGet instead - this is just to make the test fail and prove that the verify is doing it's job. But, in any case, it passes.

Comment: @Martyn Can you replace `any` in your verify method with the actual arguments?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I don't have access to the Http* method instance from outside the object. Unless I passed it into the method, but that's not really how I intend the method to be utilised. I just want verify to confirm that an instance of the correct Http* method class was used.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the proper answer to my question but I got managed to get the tests to work as intended using a custom argument matcher:

```
package uk.ac.strath.matchers;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

public class HttpMethodMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<HttpUriRequest> {

    private String expectedClassName;

    // constructors
    public HttpMethodMatcher(String expectedClassName) {
        this.expectedClassName = expectedClassName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpUriRequest httpMessage) {
        if (httpMessage.getClass().getName().equals(expectedClassName)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now in my test, I can do:

```
verify(mockHttpClient, times(1)).execute( argThat(new HttpMethodMatcher( HttpGet.class.getName() )) );
```

This tutorial was helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers